# How to allow in Github merging Pull Requests into master/main, but protecting pushing directly

Tags: github, branching-and-merging

We want to block people from pushing directly to master. But we also want people to be able to merge their PRs into master.

I've tried selecting `Restrict who can push to matching branches` on the master branch. This automatically selects an option to allow `Organization administrators, repository administrators, and users with the Maintain role.`.

Then if I have a team with a Maintain role, they can still push directly to master. If I downgrade this permission to 'Write', they then cannot merge PRs.

Is there a way round this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to enable [Require pull request reviews before merging.](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/managing-a-branch-protection-rule)

> When enabled, all commits must be made to a non-protected branch and
> submitted via a pull request with the required number of approving
> reviews and no changes requested before it can be merged into a branch
> that matches this rule.

By doing this it should let you stop pushing straight into master.
In addition you can enable **Require status checks to pass before merging.** Once again this will stop users pushing directly into master as status checks would not have passed.

In this workflow you can decide if Admin's are exempt from these rules.

Comment: didnt work for me